# Using services on Fedora 11 running as non-root

Tags: fedora

I've got a daemon that I want to launch on startup using the standard `service` framework (e.g. a file in `/etc/init.d/rc.d`, launched using `/sbin/service`). I've written scripts for the service framework before, so I don't need basic knowledge there.

However, I've never tried to run a process that shouldn't be launched as root. The process itself doesn't support chrooting on startup, and I don't want to run it as root. Short of using `su` or `sudo` in the launch script, is there any preferred or recommended way to say "run this script on startup as user X"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question is similar to this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394984/best-practice-to-run-linux-service-as-a-different-user

I'd suggest checking several of the mentioned options

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps setuid is what you are looking for? If the daemon is running as root you can create a new accoun with limited permissions (just enough perms to run the daemon) and setuid to that account in the daemon

Comment: The problem is that setuid is the right answer if I control the source code for the process, but I don't. I'm looking for something I can do in the service script itself rather than inside the actual daemon process.